# Running an executable using .bat file with sound in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, batch-file

I have an `.exe` file which plays some audio files, and I want to run it when the PC starts. There are some `.wav` files in the same folder (that the exe uses them).

 Putting the `.exe` and the `.wav` files in the `startup` folder causes multiple windows of Media Player to open together with the `.exe` file, and this is not the thing I want to happen.
So I tried to put my file in the directory `C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe`, and put a `.bat` file that starts the `.exe` in the `startup` folder:

```
start C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe
```

It starts the `.exe` file, but the sounds are not played correctly.
In addition, the sounds **do** play correctly when I open the cmd in the same folder and start the exe using `myApp.exe` command.
What is happening? Is there a flag in the `.bat` file I have to add to the `.bat` in order to run the `.exe` with sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably easier to create a task in Task Scheduler and execute the .exe directly.

Based upon the screen shot below, 2 options could suffice, either

`When the computer starts`
or
`When I log on`

[image]

To find it, click the Windows menu (start menu) and type in `task s` and it should appear in the list